# Which direction is an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

This question is related to LaTeX, however, the question itself is about English.

I am using LaTeX for a document, but since it doesn't use smart quotes or things like that, a question arises:
In a basic phrase like `people's`, should the apostrophe face forward or backward? (Forward means the end of a subquote, backward means the beginning)

Comment: Forwards. Some try to use the backtick ` as an apostrophe or single-quote. IMO it looks horrible.

Comment: In LaTeX, that turns into a quote.

Comment: So what happens when you use the keyboard character ' ?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on the [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) that answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could *just about* be about English, since other languages have other forms of apostrophe, but a simple Google search provides the answer.

Here's an excerpt from the first results of a Google Books search for ***people's***:

[image: Screenshot]
([*Conservation and Mobile Indigenous Peoples*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mR-ew3KVWA0C&pg=PA1&dq=people%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcnMP1qLHpAhW1olwKHTmkAPgQ6AEIYjAG#v=onepage&q=people's&f=false), Chatty & Colchester, Berghahn 2002)

However, even typing ***people’s*** in Windows, using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for the apostrophe, provides a result, which could also be seen by looking online for examples.

Other “printers’ quotes” follow the 6–9 rule: six comes before nine, and opening quotes look like 6 with closing quotes looking like 9. Since an apostrophe is a closing quote (see *printers’*) it's a 9.

Comment: Since *printers'* is a 9, would _printer's_ be a 9?

Comment: "Since an apostrophe is a closing quote, it's a 9". That is, it's the same character as a closing quote, even if it's not actually at the end of a word.

Comment: Alright then. I just needed a clarification